# Woocommerce cron job - change order status for orders individually

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cron

I have created a custom cronjob to my Wordpress Woocommerce website.

What does this cronjob do?
This cronjob is about to change woocommerce order status from custom order status "shipped" to completed in 3days after it is changed to shipped.

Problem: This cron job change all orders in status "shipped" to completed each time its called for run. So cron job runs every 3days but when I set order status to "shipped" 1 hour before cron is about to run it change the order status to completed.

What do I need: I need to scan each order separatelly and run cronjob every 3 days for each order on its own. So it change order status to "completed" within 3 days when the current order status was changed to "shipped". So not to apply this cron to all orders but for each order individually.

My code is bellow.

```
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'isa_add_every_three_days' );
function isa_add_every_three_days( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['every_three_days'] = array(
            'interval'  => 259200,
            'display'   => __( 'Kazde 3 dni', 'textdomain' )
    );
    return $schedules;
}

function schedule_on_hold_complete() {
  if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'on_hold_complete' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_three_days', 'on_hold_complete' );
  }
}
add_action( 'init', 'schedule_on_hold_complete' );


function on_hold_complete() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
    'post_status'       => 'wc-shipped',
);

$orderList = get_posts($args);

foreach ($orderList as $orderPost) {
    $order = new WC_Order($orderPost->ID);
    $order->update_status('completed');
  }
}
add_action( 'on_hold_complete', 'on_hold_complete' );
```

Thank you for taking a look at my problem.

Comment: You should use instead the **powerful advanced scheduled events** *(already used by Woocommerce and Woocommerce Subscriptions)*: here the [free plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/action-scheduler/), here [the documentation](https://actionscheduler.org/) or the [library to be included in a plugin](https://github.com/woocommerce/action-scheduler/)…